# Why are nutrition questions off limits?

Tags: discussion, scope

This site seeks to promote physical fitness. Obviously aerobic exercises and lifting weights can help someone achieve fitness, but so can improved nutrition. Why are we preventing questions centered around better nutrition?

Comment: Because we tried that years ago and it didn't work. There are several discussions about it here on Meta

Comment: Do a search for ["nutrition"](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=nutrition) and you can read through the history.